# Datanode not able to contact name node on AWS

Tags: hadoop2

I am trying to setup a hadoop cluster on AWS with two datanodes and one namenode.

I have followed tutorial point multinode cluster setup. I have started the name node and secondary name node and datanodes from the namenode server.
Datanode is started but not able to connect to the name node. I get the following error:

```
17/02/06 13:31:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/172.31.3.137:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
```

Comment: Is your namenode service running?

Comment: yes it is running

Comment: Can you please post the `core-site.xml` and the `/etc/hosts` files